# How to: variadic wrapper function that catches exceptions of input function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, function-templates

I am trying to create a function that I can pass other functions, which will catch any errors, but otherwise simply return the return value of the function. Here's what I've tried:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fun(int input)
{
    return input;
}

template <typename F, typename...Args>
static auto HandledCall(const F& function, Args...args)
-> decltype(function(...args))
{
    try
    {
        return function(...args);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << HandledCall(fun,1) << std::endl; // this should return 1
    std::cout << HandledCall(fun,-1) << std::endl; // this should return 0      
    return 0;
}
```

I hope the intention is relatively clear; I want `HandledCall` to be able to receive any kind of function, and return its return value (as long as `NULL` is implicitly castable to this value in the case of an error). However, when I try to compile the above code I get these kinds of errors;

> prog.cpp:10:78: error: expected primary-expression before ‘...’ token 
>   static auto HandledCall(const F& function, Args...args) ->
>   decltype(function(...args))

Clearly I'm not doing this variadic templates thing correctly... Any suggestions?

Comment: `...` alone is not enough, you need to give the parameter a name and use that name with the currently lonely `...`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I've made an attempt at this and updated the question, but I'm still getting errors..

Comment: That's because `...args` should be `args...`

Comment: What's the logic behind having such a function? It automatically catches all exceptions and then **ignores** them. The point of throwing an exception is not to be ignored. While in certain circumstances, ignoring an exception is just the right thing to do, it is not good in general and a general templated function-call wrapper calls for abuse. Moreover, you should rather name if `CallAndIgnoreExceptions()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fun(int input)
{
    return input;
}

template <typename T> struct ReturnType;

template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct ReturnType<Ret(Args...)> 
{
   typedef Ret type;
};


template <typename F, typename...Args>
static auto HandledCall(const F& function, Args...args) -> typename ReturnType<F>::type
{
    try
    {
        return function(args...);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        return typename ReturnType<F>::type{0};
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << HandledCall(fun,1) << std::endl; // this should return 1
    std::cout << HandledCall(fun,-1) << std::endl; // this should return 0      
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**

An improved version of `HandledCall` (Thanks to Mankarse):

```
template <typename F, typename...Args>
static auto HandledCall(const F& function, Args&&...args) -> typename ReturnType<F>::type
{
    try
    {
        return function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        return typename ReturnType<F>::type{0};
    }
}
```

Comment: Ideally, you would write it as `/*...*/HandledCall(F &&function, Args... &&args) /*...*/ return std::forward<F>(function)(std::forward<Args>(args)...); /*...*/`, in order to perfectly forward the arguments from the call site.

Comment: Should have been `HandledCall(const F& function, Args&&...args)`

Comment: @BЈовић That seems right to me. I updated the answer. I am on uncertain ground here. I need to shore up my understanding of perfect forwarding.

Comment: @Jason See my previous comment and the updated answer.

Comment: You might also want a specialization for functions with void return type.

Comment: I've posted an answer which shows how to handle functions with void return type. It simply requires wrapping the creation of your default return value inside a function.

Comment: Do _not_ use a trait like `ReturnType`. Use `std::result_of` instead, or plain `decltype`.

Comment: [`catch(...) { return {}; }` avoids a lot of this machinery.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/972d2549505085aa)

Answer (score 4):

The return type of the function call can be determined using [`std::result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of).

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type
    HandledCall(F&& func, Args&&... args)
{
    using result_type = typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type;
    try {
        return std::forward<F>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } catch(...) {
        return result_type();
    }
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1a5b80c074d666f)

Comment: I thought something like `std::result_of` might be available but didn't know exactly what to look for. Thanks for the pointer :)

Comment: You may want to modify this to handle cases where F has a void return type. Preferably by finding an even cleaner way to solve the problem than the one in my answer (which shamelessly plagiarizes yours). ;)

Comment: @Agentlien Take a look at the "Live demo" link, it does handle void.

Comment: Really? If I try HandledCall(bar) it gives me an error. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42ebd7a0785d580b

Comment: @Agentlien Hah! I only tested it within the `decltype` expression, which is unevaluated, so it didn't trigger that error. Fixed now. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version based on the solution presented by @Praetorian but which also works for functions with a `void` return type. The reason the other answers could not handle this case is the explicit instantiation of an object of type `void`.

```
template<typename T> 
T default_value(){return {};}

template<>
void default_value<void>(){}

template<typename F, typename... Args>
typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type
  HandledCall(F&& func, Args&&... args)
{
  try {
      return std::forward<F>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  } catch(...) {
      return default_value<typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type>();
  }
}
```

The reason this works is because the standard allows explicitly returning void values in a function with void return type.

Comment: This is an older answer, but are there any reasonable modifications that can be made to get this to work with class member functions? As it stands, this only works with free functions.

Comment: Actually, this solution works fine if you use `std::bind` on the member function. But you still have to cast the first argument of the bind statement if you are trying to call an overloaded function which looks horribly nasty.